# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: error, central-administration

After installing Sharepoint 2010 I am getting an error in Central Administration:

> "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable"

Everthing was working fine, but after some time the central admin shows this error.
The IIS service is getting stopped automatically.

Comment: http://patricklamber.blogspot.com/2010/11/sharepoint-2010-returns-503-service.html

after 2 days of struggle finally The blog helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the linked web site with the solution might not be accessable in future, here a short summery of what caused the error:

A domain group policy overrided an permission of the application pool accounts called “Log on as a batch job”. Without this permission the app pool cannot run properly.